# T SQL - Active Directory - Generate table containing memberof information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, active-directory, common-table-expression

I would like to generate a table in my TSQL database that contains information on all users from active directory and which groups they are members of.

I've read a few articles but can't seem to get anything to work correctly.

The best I currently have is:

```
   DECLARE @UserGroup table (LdapGroup nvarchar(max))
   INSERT INTO @UserGroup exec dbo.GetLdapUserGroups username
   select * from @UserGroup
```

This returns

```
**LdapGroup**
group1
group2
...
```

I would like the ability to be able to generate a single table that contains the group information for all users in Active Directory.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a linked service setup in your SQL instance to AD?

Comment: There is a "Linked Server" setup in the SQL instance that is connected to AD. As mentioned above I can return results for one user e.g. Column 1 = LdapGroup, row 1 col 1  = groupname1, row 2 col 2 = groupname 2 etc... But can't figure out how to get results for all users

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Windows Explorer Directory?  If so, I'd use Excel for this, now SQL Server.  See the link below.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Click 'Download Now' to get the sample file.  That will show you the contents of all folders and sub-folders.  Once you have the hierarchy in Excel, it's a simple loading exercise to get it into SQL Server.  You could use VBA, in Excel, to do the loading work for you.